# JBoss property in .properties file does not work

Tags: java, properties, jboss, filenotfoundexception, jboss-4.2.x

In my Java `.properties` file I have this line:

```
KEYSTORE_PATH=${jboss.server.data.dir}/myapp/keys/keystore.jks
```

In all other files e.g. `log4j.properties` `jboss.server.data.dir` is changed to `C:\\jboss\server\default\log` and it's ok.

But here I get this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${jboss.server.data.dir}\myapp\keys\keystore.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

It looks like JBoss does not change its property name to the `dir` name.

Comment: What version of JBoss are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading your properties file via the `java.util.Properties` type, there is no special handling of value placeholders.  There are several third party libraries that provide such capabilities.  [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework) being one of them.

Another option is to use the -C command line option when starting JBoss 4.x to specify a custom properties file.  When loaded, JBoss will resolve the value placeholders correctly.  The loaded, fully resolved properties can then be accessed via the various `System.getProperties` and `System.getProperty` methods.